# How do I select half this shape and delete/remove it? (Affinity 1.7)

Tags: vector, selections, affinity-designer

[image]

I have a star made on the canvas, but I can't find a standard selection box to select only half and then delete it.

Comment: You seem to have already been happy with a rasterized shape from which a part is deleted after making a selection marquee in pixel editing mode. Affinity D allows also many vector edits. You can keep the shape as vector if you subtract from it a rectangle which covers the unwanted half.

Comment: I've added a more in-depth answer covering the excellent point raised by @user287001 - there are some far better approaches which *keep* your work pure vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can keep your shape vector and cut it in half leaving it node-editable and more useful with either of two easy approaches:

**1. Boolean Operation**

Draw out a rectangle shape over the part you wish to subtract, snapping to points to get it exactly located. Click the **Subtraction Boolean** icon in the toolbar above, and the item which is *in front* will be subtracted from the item behind.

[image]

As you can see here, switching to the **Node Selection** tool you can tell this is still vector - hasn't been rasterised - and is thus far more useful overall.

[image]

**2. Convert to Curves**

Select your shape, and click the **Convert to Curves** button on the toolbar above. this takes away the automated shape controllers, but make the resulting vector curve node-by-node editable.

[image]

Use the **Node Selection** tool and drag a rectangular marquee over half your nodes to select them - like so:

[image]

Then hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key on your keyboard - this will be your result:

[image]

Which should get you what you need with ***far*** greater *operational flexibility* than rasterising your layer; there are cases where rasterising is not only called for but super-helpful, but in general I tend to keep things vector as much as possible.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First: put the vector (star image) on that background and press "Enter"
Then go to the layer option and then select your vector layer. Right click on that, then press "Resterize layer"
Second: use "Rectangular Marquee Tool" to cut your vector according to your will.
Cutting technique: select the half of your vector with "Rectangular Marquee Tool" and press [Ctrl with x]

Comment: Thank you. It is also necessary to switch to Pixel Persona for Rectangular Marquee. Took me a minute. https://i.imgur.com/7L4EBaY.png

Comment: *For your future reference*: You ***don't*** *need* to rasterise the layer to complete this operation; if you overlay a rectangle shape over the half to remove, and click the appropriate subtract boolean button, you get a live vector curve - still editable and useful.